# Which way is good to build eosio.cdt?

Tags: eosio.cdt, build, installation

I am following this documentation, https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/development-environment/install-the-CDT which is used for installing **eosio cdt**. It has two ways for doing this.

> The first is:

```
wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases/download/v1.6.3/eosio.cdt_1.6.3-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio.cdt_1.6.3-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
```

> And the second way is (Install from source):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/eosio/eosio.cdt --branch v1.6.3 --single-branch
cd eosio.cdt
./build.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

I am curious, the first one takes very less time to execute while the second one takes very long time. My question is, generally which method should be used? OR do we need to execute all these commands? Please guide and correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one installs a prebuild binary package, the second one builds eosio.cdt from source (first compiles the code to an executable etc.), that's why first one is so much faster.

There are several reasons why you can choose the second option, e.g.

- incompatibility of OS and package (you have to build it yourself)
- if you want to make changes to the cdt
- if you distrust the package
- if you want to build a special version, a pre-release, development-branch
- if minor changes have been made that are not included in the package

But the usual choice is the first one.

Comment: In the case of deploying `eosio.system` contracts which needs to switch between versions, will first option work?